# NullReferenceException was unhandled Object reference not set to an instance of an object. c#

Tags: c#, nullpointerexception

I tried running my program, and have also compared my code to my friend's code, but the error keeps on showing up even though we tried changing these lines (which I think where the error is coming from):

```
try
{
    FileStream b = new FileStream(@"C:\User\User_2\Desktop\board.txt", FileMode.Open);
    StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(b);

    int x = 0;
    while (!stream.EndOfStream)
    {
        if (x == 0)
            g1 = stream.ReadLine().Split(' ');
        else if (x == 1)
            g2 = stream.ReadLine().Split(' ');
        else if (x == 2)
            g3 = stream.ReadLine().Split(' ');

        x++;
    }
    stream.Close();
    b.Close();
}
catch (Exception e) { }
```

The program is used to check for a text file which contains these 3 lines:

```
O . X 
X O .
X . O
```

...and see if there is a winner.

This is the part where Visual Studio highlights the error:

```
int n = 0;
int m = n + 1;
int o = m + 1;

Boolean result = false;
int winner = 0;
string dw = "";

while (n <= 2)
{
    // In this if-statement is the error:
    if (g1[n].Equals(g2[n]) && g2[n].Equals(g3[n]) && !g1[n].Equals("."))
    {
        result = true;
        winner++;
        dw = g1[n];
    }
    if (g1[n].Equals(g1[m]) && g1[m].Equals(g1[o]) && !g1[n].Equals("."))
    {
        result = true;
        winner++;
        dw = g1[n];
    }
    else if (g2[n].Equals(g2[m]) && g2[m].Equals(g2[o]) && !g2[n].Equals("."))
    {
        result = true;
        winner++;
        dw = g2[n];
    }
    else if (g3[n].Equals(g3[m]) && g3[m].Equals(g3[o]) && !g3[n].Equals("."))
    {
        result = true;
        winner++;
        dw = g3[n];
    }
    else if (g1[n].Equals(g2[m]) && g2[m].Equals(g3[o]) && !g1[n].Equals("."))
    {
        result = true;
        winner++;
        dw = g1[n];
    }
    else if (g3[n].Equals(g2[m]) && g2[m].Equals(g1[o]) && !g3[n].Equals("."))
    {
        result = true;
        winner++;
        dw = g3[n];
    }
    n++;
}
```

I really don't know what to do know, I can't make it work.

EDIT: I tried printing out the values of the arrays before the if statements but it doesn't print anything out. Sorry guys, I'm really new here.

Comment: What happen if you have only two lines in the input file?

Comment: what exactly are g1/g2/g3 and where are they defined?

Comment: @Rahul the error is in the title, I guess.
to OP: which of the variables does Visual Studio mark as being null?

Comment: bad boy, try working out that small assignment yourself :)

Comment: why do people vote questions like this down?  He's clearly new, and he seems to be putting effort into solving his problem

Comment: **if (g1[n].Equals(g2[n]) && g2[n].Equals(g3[n]) && !g1[n].Equals("."))** -- visual studio is pointing here for the error.

Comment: a nullref exception will be thrown on that line if: g1 is null, g2 is null, g3 is null, item at index n in g1 is null, item at index n in g2 is null, or item at index n in g3 is null. if you split up the long if-statement into boolean expressions first it may help you to isolate your problem.

Comment: Where are g1, g2 and g3 initialized? They seem to appear out of nowhere in the code you've posted.

Comment: I actually tried doing it, I passed it already, I just want to know what to do to make it work, we have a test tomorrow.:( the three string arrays are being pointed as null actually, they don't store the lines from the txt file.

Comment: @Jonesy: because the question is missing some important information and is hard to comprehend. If OP fixes those problem with the question, the downvotes will/should start going away

Comment: the g1,g2, and g3 were initialized immediately in the class.

            String[] g1 = new String[3];
            String[] g2 = new String[3];
            String[] g3 = new String[3];


            try
            {

Comment: step through your while loop and see if g1,g2,g3 are getting assigned correctly.

Comment: Sorry, I really don't know how to ask properly here, I tried my best to ask clearly.:(

Comment: @Steve I really haven't tried that since this was just an exercise for us.:)

Comment: @Carko I can see that, it just doesn't seem very friendly/welcoming.  I'll start a no downvotes for newbies campaign

Comment: @Jonesy I tried printing out the values of the arrays, but it didn't print out anything, that's why I actually pointed it out at the first part of my question that the arrays don't store the values from the txt file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, try reading the file like this:

```
using System.IO;

try
{
    var file = @"C:\User\User_2\Desktop\board.txt";
    var lines = File.ReadAllLines(file).ToList();
    var g1 = lines[0].Split(' ');
    var g2 = lines[1].Split(' ');
    var g3 = lines[2].Split(' ');
}
catch (Exception e) 
{ 
    throw e; 
}
```

Probably now you'll get an exception thrown.

The line `catch (Exception e) { }`  is the culprit for not being notified that there is an exception. You should always handle the exceptions that you catch in your code.

**P.S.** Probably you have to use `C:\Users\...` in the path, instead of `C:\User\...`. Anyway, make sure that you use a valid path to your file.

Comment: A DirectoryNotFoundException Could not find a part of the path 'C:\User\User_2\Desktop\board.txt'. shows up.

Comment: And you are absolutely sure that the file: _C:\User\User_2\Desktop\board.txt_ exists on the computer were the application runs?

Comment: I just realized it now, yeah there was something wrong with the path. It worked on my pc, but it didn't in the one I'm using in school. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When using `Equals` you must ensure the object you are calling is not null;

```
object oneValue = 1;
object nullValue = null;

var result = nullValue.Equals(oneValue); // Throws NullReferenceException because nullValue is null
```

You could use the equality operator instead.

```
string oneValue = "1";
string nullValue = null;

var result = nullValue == oneValue; // False
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `==` operator instead of the `Equals` method, which needs the object to be instantiated. But then you still need to make sure the value isn't null.

Comment: The problem is, the file is not being read correctly, i think, and the lines are not being stored in the array.